# Error InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected using hybrid_property

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, properties, hybrid

I have the following model class:

```
class ArticleOptionSetModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sdt_articles_options_sets'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence("sdq_articles_options_sets"), primary_key=True)
    article_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sdt_articles.id'), nullable=False)
    option_set_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sdt_options_sets.id'), nullable=False)
    order_num = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    def have_options(self, article_id) -> int:
        result = db.session.query(func.count(ArticleOptionSetModel.id))\
                                  .join(OptionSetModel, ArticleOptionSetModel.option_set_id == OptionSetModel.id)\
                                  .filter(ArticleOptionSetModel.article_id == self.article_id)\
                                  .filter(OptionSetModel.option_type == OT_OPTION).one()
        if result[0] > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

If I try to use this model in a join, and extract the field:

```
        result = db.session.query(ArticleModel.id,
                                  ArticleOptionSetModel.have_options)\
            .join(ArticleOptionSetModel, ArticleModel.id == ArticleOptionSetModel.article_id)

        return result.all()
```

I get this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '1'

where 1 is the value returned from my method.

The 0 or 1 returned from the method should be considered as column result in the caller query.
How it's possible to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You should return

```
select([1])

or select([0])
```

to return as SQL entity.